# emacs autoload modes

Tags: emacs, global, yasnippet

I am a newbie.
Now I want to

> auto start yasnippet auto-complete gtags flymake modes

when I opening a (php/java/el/...) file.

> What Should I put in my emacs config file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As liu says, you use `add-hook` to specify that an action be run when a particular mode is started. Documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks.html#Hooks). Hooks are analogous to *events* in C#, or the *observer pattern* in OOP.

Every mode should define a hook that is run when that mode is started, eg. for a mode named *java-mode* there is a corresponding hook called *java-mode-hook*. `add-hook` lets you wire an action to this hook:

```
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'my-action)
```

You can use anonymous `lambda` functions to define the action in-place, like so:

```
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook (lambda () (message "hello from java-mode")))
```

This will print a message whenever you start up java mode.

It is usually better to define a named function for the purpose. If you use named functions, `add-hook` will ensure the same function is not called multiple times.

```
  (defun hello () 
    (message "hello from java-mode"))

  (add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'hello)
```

Language editing modes are derived from prog-mode. If you want to run an action when you start up any programming language mode, you add your function to `prog-mode-hook`.

---

You need to manually configure autocomplete mode for each mode you want to use it in. For each mode, add that mode to the `ac-modes` list:

```
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'java-mode)
```

As a side note, you will want to use `flyspell-prog-mode` for programming language modes, so you only receive spelling suggestions in comments and string literals.

```
(defun on-prog-mode ()
  (flyspell-prog-mode t))

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'on-prog-mode)
```

And you will probably want to use [flycheck](https://github.com/lunaryorn/flycheck) instead of the older flymake. Flycheck is under active development and has checkers for php.

Comment: prog-mode-hook is  what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

you can add just like below:

```
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

then update below accordingly:

```
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook (lambda () (flyspell-mode 1)))
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook (lambda()(gtags-mode 1)))
```

Comment: if i want to auto start gtags for java, should I also put (add-hook 'java-mode-hook xxxx) ? Is there anyway to enable those whatever file (java/php/...) I am opening?